# Error inserting (unicode?) text into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database that I have created which I'm filling with data from a db2 database.  I get an error when I run the following:

```
for row in db2_connection.execute(query):
    sqlite3_connection.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?, ?)", row)
```

Here's the error:

```
File "example.py", line 72, in load_micr_db
    sqlite3_connection.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?, ?)", row)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). 
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to 
Unicode strings.
```

This sounds like excellent advice, but I don't know how to follow it.  How do I "switch my application to Unicode strings"?

I'm using Python 2.6, `pyodbc` to query db2 9, `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string literals prefixed with a `u`.

```
print u'I am a Unicode string.'
```

["Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Can you unpack that?  I switched my second line (from the above example to `sqlite3_connection.execute(u"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (?, ?, ?)", row)` and still received the same error.  Perhaps I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: The elements in `row` *also* need to be `unicode` if they're strings.

Comment: My db2 source was returning strings that needed to be decoded to unicode using 'latin-1'.  Thanks for your help.