# Inserting unicode into sqlite?

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I am still learning Python and as a little Project I wrote a script that would take the values I have in a text file and insert them into a sqlite3 database. But some of the names have weird letter (I guess you would call them non-ASCII), and generate an error when they come up. Here is my little script (and please tell me if there is anyway it could be more Pythonic):
    import sqlite3

```
f = open('complete', 'r')
fList = f.readlines()
conn = sqlite3.connect('tpb')
cur = conn.cursor()

for i in fList:
    exploaded = i.split('|')
    eList = (
        (exploaded[1], exploaded[5])
    )
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO magnets VALUES(?, ?)', eList)
    conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

And it generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sortinghat.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO magnets VALUES(?, ?)', eList)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a te
xt_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is
highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode str
ings.
```

Comment: Maybe this might help:

[Error inserting (unicode?) text into sqlite3 database][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939169/error-inserting-unicode-text-into-sqlite3-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the file contents into unicode you need to decode from whichever encoding it is in.
It looks like you're on Windows so a good bet is `cp1252`.
If you got the file from somewhere else all bets are off.

Once you have the encoding sorted, an easy way to decode is to use the `codecs` module, e.g.:

```
import codecs
# ...
with codecs.open('complete', encoding='cp1252') as fin: # or utf-8 or whatever
  for line in fin:
    to_insert = (line.split('|')[1], line.split('|')[5])
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO magnets VALUES (?,?)', to_insert)
    conn.commit()
# ...
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much! And thanks for showing me the `with` statement, would have never thought of it!

Comment: You made it easy by including your code and the full traceback. Cheers, and welcome to SO.